Is the insurance cost for going through the Red Sea the determining factor why ships avoid it, and are insurance companies making a big profit there?
It's been claimed in a popular video on the FSK bridge as some side comments (towards the end, last 3 minutes or so) that

The insurance companies are making money "hand over fist" in selling war insurance for sailing through the Red Sea because the Houthis aren't doing that much damage (i.e. the insurance claims paid are far below the insurance premiums collected.) https://youtu.be/2Wim-_Q_59o?t=1428

The main issue why ships prefer to go around Africa is [thus] not the Houthi attacks themselves but the high [war] insurance costs for sailing through the Red Sea right now. https://youtu.be/2Wim-_Q_59o?t=1535


These are both somewhat 'soft' claims, in that no specific numbers are advanced, and the latter does speak of motivation, but I suppose it's possible some ship owners have talked about their calculus on this.
So are these claims true?

So why don't they skip the war insurance and go through the Red Sea? Is it (3) because they can charge more for the longer journey?

FWTW, the underlying claim that insurance went up a lot for the area appears true "Cost of Red Sea shipping insurance rises 2,700% [...]  So a war insurance cost of 2 percent for a vessel worth $100 million would mean its owner having to pay $2 million to sail through the risk area." But that doesn't get to whether most of that gets turned into profits for the insurance companies.

N.B. that article was written before the Houthis managed to sink a ship. But the video claims were made after.

@WeatherVane I doubt insuring a cargo ship is like renting a car where you check some boxes a la carte. [ ] War insurance, Red Sea. [ ] Typhoon insurance. [ ] Blocking-An-International-Shipping-Channel insurance. I expect the insurers offer to insure their entire journey, and there are only so many insurers.

@Schwern: actually, war insurance is pretty much like that https://swedishclub.com/insurance/marine/war/ A checkbox that you can check or not.

@Schwern: ibid https://www.standard-club.com/products/war-risks/

Maybe one could do a manual estimate. You already have the increase in insurance cost, there should be estimates for total traffic and the actual Houthi attacks are so few that one could list all of them. Would count as primary research and is not an answer unfortunately.

@quarague: estimating how many ships would have to be sunk for break even is relatively easy, assuming a known premium rate (e.g. that 2%) and an average value of a ship. Alas, I'm not sure how many of those passing [through the Red Sea] have war insurance. Because insurance companies don't have to pay otherwise [in those circumstances], and it turns out war insurance is optional.

One could try to estimate the total numbers of ships/ total value versus total Houthi damage so far and thus get an estimate for the break even rate of just taking the risk and compare that to the 2% the insurance companies charge.

@Schwern: a funny point in the fine print though of some of these: WW3 (defined as a war between any [two] of the five major powers) is excluded even by 'war insurance'.

@thegodsfromengineering WW3 is an act of Oh My God.

@thegodsfromengineering there is the value of the cargo too (and possibly the crew). When the Cutty Sark made its maiden voyage, the profit from that one tea cargo was greater than the capital cost of the ship.
